# Checkbox is getting selected even if i am clicking outside of it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox

I have implemented group of checkbox, so when we click particular checkbox the parameter should get selected but even if i am clicking outside the checkbox in the area of the grouping of all the checkboxes, It is being checked. help me what I am doing wrong? Only when we click on the checkbox that parameter has to be selected.

```js
 changeValue(event: any, item: any) {
    if (event) {
      this.activeParameter.paramList[item].selected = true;
      this.selectedItems.push(this.activeParameter.paramList[item].value)
    } else {
      this.activeParameter.paramList[item].selected = false;
      let selected;
      selected = this.selectedItems.filter( (data: any) => data !== this.activeParameter.paramList[item].value)
      this.selectedItems = selected;
    }
    this.activeParamCount = this.selectedItems.length;
    this.groupSelected = undefined;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parameter-list" *ngFor="let paramCategorie of activeParameter.groupList">
            <div class="groupSelection-header"  >{{paramCategorie.lable}}</div>
            <label class="groupList" *ngFor="let param of paramCategorie.paramList">
              <input type="checkbox" (ngModelChange)="changeValue($event, param)"[disabled]='!activeParameter.paramList[param].selected && activeParamCount > 11'
              [(ngModel)]='activeParameter.paramList[param].selected'> 
                <span class="checkmark" [ngClass]= "!activeParameter.paramList[param].selected && activeParamCount >= 12? 'checkmark-disable ' : ' '" ></span>
                <span class="param-label" [ngClass]="{'unchecked':!activeParameter.paramList[param].selected && activeParamCount < 12, 'checked':activeParameter.paramList[param].selected && activeParamCount<= 11, 'disabled': !activeParameter.paramList[param].selected && activeParamCount > 11 }">
                {{activeParameter.paramList[param] ? activeParameter.paramList[param].label : "NA"}}
              </span>
            </label>
          </div>
```

Comment: post more code.

Comment: post more code.

Comment: updated the code can you please check now

Comment: can you create demo on https://codesandbox.io and post URL ?

Comment: try only [ngModel] and in function changeEvent, write `activeParameter.paramList[param].selected=event` at first

Comment: can you please explain a bit @Eliseo ?

Comment: and if i dont use ngModelChange, then how we are calling the function from DOM?

Comment: nor,. I want to say use [ngModel] and (ngModelChange), but NOT [(ngModel)] and (ngModelChange)

Comment: But still issue remains the same. I checked with these changes

Comment: @ShilpiDhiman Can you provide me sample JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

## You can try to this way #

```
 changeValue(event: any, item: any) {
  this.activeParameter.paramList[item].selected = !this.activeParameter.paramList[item].selected;
if (this.activeParameter.paramList[item].selected === true) {
  this.selectedItems.push(this.activeParameter.paramList[item].value)
} else {
  this.activeParameter.paramList[item].selected = false;
  let selected;
  selected = this.selectedItems.filter( (data: any) => data !== this.activeParameter.paramList[item].value)
  this.selectedItems = selected;
}
this.activeParamCount = this.selectedItems.length;
this.groupSelected = undefined;
```

}